# Alternative to rollapplyr

Tags: r

Hi I have data frame as below

```
DF1
rid     date      A     B      C
1      2014      34    66     12
2      2014      55    NA     NA
3      2014      53    77     12
4      2014      66    12     12
5      2014      77    12     11
6      2014      22    10     NA
7      2014      11    13     11
.
600000 2015      3     34     15
```

I am trying to get mean for col 'B' grouped by col 'C' in the new col 'D'
   here is my below code which is  taking huge time to process, Any alternative which computes in fastest way

```
df2=df1 %>%
    group_by(C) %>%
    mutate(D=rollapplyr(B, 600000, mean, partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE) )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `RcppRoll` package

Comment: the width and the number of rows are both 600000, wouldn't a regular mean do just the same ?

Comment: Hi Sotos, if give a maximum width as 600000 then D value giving only NA values  df2= df1%>%
   group_by(C) %>%
   mutate(roll_sum = roll_mean(B, 600000 , align = "right", fill = NA,na.rm = FALSE))

Comment: Yes Moody width is 600000 which is max

Comment: becaz i need to calculate mean from row 1 group by C